# How to set context menu width to match choice box

Tags: javafx, java-8, scenebuilder, dropdownchoice

I created ChoiceBox using scene builder 2.0 and attached to IntelliJ Idea and add below code to add item to ChoiceBox in Main class

```
ChoiceBox genderBox = (ChoiceBox) scene.lookup("#gender");
genderBox.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList("Boy", "Girl"));
genderBox.getSelectionModel().select(0);
```

Choice box code from FXML is as below

```
<ChoiceBox id="gender" prefHeight="16.0" prefWidth="150.0" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="11">
           <GridPane.margin>
              <Insets left="10.0" />
           </GridPane.margin>
</ChoiceBox>
```

Anyway, when running the Main class I see the choice box as below. choice box width is not matched with context menu(popup) width.

[image: gender choice box]

How to set a width to the context menu?

**EDIT**

Anyway setting width to the context menu in combo box is working fine. So I moved with combo box. [see example fxml.](https://github.com/laki88/PatientDischargeForm/blob/master/src/main/resources/fxml/patientDischargeForm.fxml#L158)

Answer (score 0):

First, set width of the ChoiceBox itself...

```
<ChoiceBox prefWidth="150">
    ...
</ChoiceBox>
```

Then, set width of the popup list via CSS...

```
.choice-box .menu-item > .label {
    -fx-pref-width: 100;
}
```

note: the box is about 50px wider than the list because of the drop-down button.